# How to by-pass first time configuration dilaog of the scanner

Tags: c#, windows-services

I have a Windows service application written in C# and Visual Studio 2010. My operating system is Windows 7. My application makes some operations about scanners.

The problem is that if a scanner is newly installed and will be used for first time the scanner automatically opens a configuration window for first time usage. As you know in Windows 7 a service cannot open a window even if you check the "Allow service to interact with desktop" checkbox. Even so I don't want to show that kind of window to end user.

In debug mode I don't have any problem. I mean the application has no error. The window comes to screen, I click OK and continue without any problem. But if I run my application as a  Windows service it cannot open this window and hangs. It does not timeout, does not throw error, just waits. The mentioned window has a screenshot blow:

[image: First time configuration window for Canon DR-M140 Scanner]

I have this problem for both ISIS and TWAIN scanners.

So how can I get rid of those kind of windows? Is there a way of sending confirmation message to any kind of requests that come from a process? Can I do something with threads, backgroundworker etc?

Any advise?

Comment: So your, Service is starting which is already a good point. Have you tried initializing all scanners first to check if some of them are not "on" or "available" because it could be that your Service is already doing some work with scanners that aren't even here.

Comment: No, service cannot do anything with unavailable scanners. That service gives active scanner list to user. User select one of them. The problem occurs when the user clicks "Scan" button. Becuase it cannot show first-time configuration window to user but also waits for user confirmation to continue.